# How to implement a class in a method when it already has a parameter to be specified?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

So I'm following a Udemy tutorial for Android Studio and making a trivia app. So here's the deal:
Here's a file QuestionBank.java:

```
package com.example.triviaapp.data;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.triviaapp.controller.AppController;
import com.example.triviaapp.models.Question;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class QuestionBank {

    ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    private String url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json";


    public List<Question> getQuestions(Context context){
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                (JSONArray) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
                        for (int i = 0; i >= response.length(); i ++){
                            try {
                                questionArrayList.add(new Question(response.getJSONArray(i).getString(0),response.getJSONArray(i).getBoolean(1)));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        AppController.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
        return questionArrayList;
    }

}
```

As you see, when I call it in the Main activity, I need to provide context (this).
This line

> AppController.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);

Was meant to be

> AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);

As given by the teacher, but I was having an error that getInstance needs context. I found the solution thanks to SO, and made the changes (AppController is the singleton class btw).

So, I needed to get context from the MainActivity when it was run and had to change this

> public List getQuestions(){

to this:

> public List getQuestions(Context context){

Problem fixed! (however the teacher didn't get any error whatsoever, I don't know why.)

Then in a later video, he said we need getQuestions() to implement a class final AnswerListAsyncResponse callback.

So the line I modified is supposed to be this:

> public List getQuestions(final AnswerListAsyncResponse callback){

While mine already has Context context in the brackets. What should I do?

Comment: Apart of what you're asking here, you should [type your variables with interfaces](http://www.thefinestartist.com/effective-java/52), instead of implementations. So `ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();` becomes `List<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();` (also, `questionList` would be a better name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple parameters to a function.

In your case, you can pass both context and callback like this

```
public List getQuestions(Context context, final AnswerListAsyncResponse callback){}
```